# Help with algorithmic complexity in custom merge sort implementation

Tags: algorithms, sorting, big-o, algorithm-analysis

I've got [an implementation](https://github.com/seanochoa/sorted/tree/master/cpp) of the merge sort in C++ using a custom doubly linked list.  I'm coming up with a big O complexity of n^2, based on the `merge_sort()` > `slice` operation.  But, from [what I've read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), this algorithm *should* be `n*log(n)`, where the log has a base of two.

Can someone help me determine if I'm just determining the complexity incorrectly, or if the implementation can/should be improved to achieve `n*log(n)` complexity?

If you would like some background on my goals for this project, see [my blog](http://cdmnky.blogspot.com).  I've added comments in the code outlining what I understand the complexity of each method to be.

*Clarification* - I'm focusing on the C++ implementation with this question.  I've got another implementation written in Python, but that was something that was added in addition to my original goal(s).

Answer (score 2):

You're determining the complexity incorrectly. The standard mergesort recurrence is

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n)
```

Since your `slice` is indeed `O(n)`, you're fine.

As a minor optimisation, though, you might want to consider having a single method to split the list in two which doesn't involve iterating down the first half of the list twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here.  I'm trying to understand your suggested optimization.  I assume you're talking about the `slice` method, but I don't see where its iterating down the first half twice.

Comment: @bitcycle, `left = original->slice(0,(len/2)); right = original->slice((len/2)+1,len-1);` between them appear to iterate over the list 1.5 times.